# Accessing a child class from another child class inside parent class

Tags: python, pylons

I really didn't know what title I should choose. Anyway, I have code like this (this is [fixtures](http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture)):

```
from fixture import DataSet

class CategoryData(DataSet):
    class cat1:
        name = 'Category 1'
    class cat2:
        name = 'Category 2'
        parent = cat1
```

The problem is I can't reference cat1 in cat2 like that:

```
File "/home/julas/cgp/cgp/datasets/__init__.py", line 11, in cat2
    parent = cat1
NameError: name 'cat1' is not defined
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, Python doesn't do nested scoping like that for you.  To access `CategoryData.cat1`, you need to spell it out.

Second, and a bigger issue, is that there's no way to access `CategoryData` from there: the class hasn't been defined yet, since you're in the middle of defining it.  If you do this:

```
class Object(object):
    a = 1
    b = Object.a
```

it'll fail, because the value of `Object` isn't assigned until the end of the class definition.  You can think of it as happening like this:

```
class _unnamed_class(object):
    a = 1
    b = Object.a
Object = _unnamed_class
```

There's no way to reference `a` from where `b` is assigned, because the containing class hasn't yet been assigned its name.

In order to assign `parent` as a class property, you need to assign it after the containing class actually exists:

```
class CategoryData(DataSet):
    class cat1:
        name = 'Category 1'
    class cat2:
        name = 'Category 2'
CategoryData.cat2.parent = CategoryData.cat1
```

Comment: I too use fixture and while I have not run into this issue I have seen it described. I believe that Glenn's answer will do what you want, however you'll have the definitions of your fixtures be a bit scattered and less readable. I'll be curious to see what you will end up doing.

Comment: I knew that the problem was in the definition not being finished when I tried to reference the class. I just haven't thought about moving it out of the definition. I guess I'll use that as I don't see other options. I don't know if some other format, like YAML wouldn't be better for fixtures instead of bending Python like that.

Answer (score 1):

You either:
 Move it out of the definition:

```
CategoryData.cat2.parent=CategoryData.cat1
```

Or, if it's an object attribute (and not a class attribute):

```
class cat2:
    name = 'Category 2'
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = cat1
```